# How do I use a header location in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Can I use a header location in jQuery for redirection or refresh?

Like in PHP:

```
header('location:www.google.co.in');
header("Refresh:1,url=home.php");
```

If not, what is the alternative way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Headers are interpreted prior to the rendering of the document, and before jQuery is even loaded so these aren't an option. Instead, you can redirect the browser using `document.location`.

```
document.location.href = 'www.google.co.in';
```

For a jQuery approach you can use

```
$(location).attr('href', 'www.google.co.in');
```

however I would favor the plain javascript version.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
window.location.assign('www.google.co.in');
```

or

```
window.location.href = 'www.google.co.in';
```

or

```
window.location.replace('www.google.co.in');
```

The difference is that `assign()` will just cause a new document to load. While `replace()` will replace the current document and replace the current history with that URL making it so you can't go back to the previous document loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.location.href="www.google.co.in";
```

for redirection.

and

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

to reload the page